# Python 3.5: Print Canvas Text

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Could anyone share with me how to print the text of the text widget added to a Canvas object? In the code below, I want the system return the value of "hello" when mouse on the text, however, it turns out giving me "1". Don't know why. Could anyone help me?

Many many thanks!!!

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


def show_text(event):
    print (canvas.text)

master = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master, width = 200, height = 100)
canvas.pack()
canvas.bind('<Enter>',show_text)
canvas.text = canvas.create_text(20, 30, text="hello")

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [canvas docs](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_text.html):

> You can display one or more lines of text on a canvas C by creating a
>   text object:
>
> ```
> id = C.create_text(x, y, option, ...)
> ```
>
> This returns the object ID of the text object on canvas C.

Now, you gotta modify the code something like this:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


def show_text(event):
    print (canvas.itemcget(obj_id, 'text'))

master = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master, width = 200, height = 100)
canvas.pack()
canvas.bind('<Enter>',show_text)
obj_id = canvas.create_text(20, 30, text="hello")

mainloop()
```

[image: getting-text-from-canvas]

Follow up (see the documentation for [Label.config](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method):

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def show_text(event):
    print (canvas.itemcget(canvas.text, 'text'))
    #The command of writing text 'hello' in sch_Label to replace the text 'the info shows here'
    sch_Label.config(text = 'hello!')

master = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master, width = 200, height = 100)
canvas.pack()
canvas.bind('<Enter>',show_text)
canvas.text = canvas.create_text(20, 30, text="hello")

pad1 = ttk.Notebook(master)
pad1.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=1, fill="both")
tab1 = Frame(pad1)
pad1.add(tab1, text = "Schedule")
pad1.pack(side=RIGHT)
sch_Label = ttk.Label(tab1, text='The info shows here')
sch_Label.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, that's exactly what I want. Could I have a follow-up question on this. Apart from printing hello, I also want to write the world "hello" to the tab label in a notebook widget, when the mouse is on. However, I cannot find a way to refer to a particular object apart from the widget of the event. Do you have any idea? I attach the code as below based on your version. Thanks a lot. You know, I have been writing VB and new to Python, so really don't know how it object referring system works. Your advice will save me from a lot of time!

Comment: import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def show_text(event):
    print (canvas.itemcget(canvas.text, 'text'))
    #The command of writing text 'hello' in sch_Label to replace the text 'the info shows here'
    
master = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master, width = 200, height = 100)
canvas.pack()
canvas.bind('<Enter>',show_text)
canvas.text = canvas.create_text(20, 30, text="hello")

Comment: pad1 = ttk.Notebook(master)
pad1.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=1, fill="both")
tab1 = ttk.Frame(pad1)
pad1.add(tab1, text = "Schedule")
pad1.pack(side=RIGHT)
sch_Label = ttk.Label(tab1, text='The info shows here')
sch_Label.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
mainloop()