# Text canvas widget in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
my_canvas = tk.Canvas(my_root, height=100, width=100, bg="#E5D3D0")
my_canvas.grid(row=2, column=2)
my_canvas.create_text(50, 50, text="hii")
```

I created a text canvas and now I want to access/retrieve the text present in my canvas. how can I do that?

Comment: Does this: [Answer to a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928665/python-3-5-print-canvas-text) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You would use `text_var = my_canvas.text` to set/retrieve the text

[Canvas functions](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_text.html#text)